# Connecting to SQL server via socket programming on iOS

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, ios, sockets

Is it possible to execute quires to SQL server via socket programming in iOS?

Answer (score 4):

You have four options:-

1 - Reverse engineer Microsoft's wire level sockets protocol.
    Probably man centuries worth of effort involved in this.

2 - Write a simple sockets server which can run on the SQLServer infrastructure to 
    service your SQL requests.
    Doable - but "Simple Sockets Servers" dont really exist, it could get quite messy!

3 - Write a web service using one of the many frameworks for either REST or SOAP and access the data from within IOS via http request calls.

4 - Use the web service capability built into SQLSever since 2005. [How Too](http://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/28577)

Comment: Oops - was right once! -- decided that SQLServers builtin web services was really a different option!

Comment: This isn't true. You don't have to reverse engineer anything. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

you could use http to access sql server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226553%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Yes. SQL Server uses an open protocol called TDS. In fact the SQL Server Native Client is just implementation of a TDS client. You can read the spec here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd304523.aspx